# Pulling double inverted commas from the database

Tags: php

I need some assistance. I have a table and I am loading info to it from the database, everything loads how it is in the database but as soon as I want to edit a row with a value that has a double inverted comma in it for eg: 40" Samsung. What it will do when I want to edit it it will show the 40 but everything after the 40 wont appear.

How my edit works, I have checkbox in on column of the table linked to its row so when I tick the check box and I select edit all the information on that row(s) will be present on their respected textboxes and I edit the info and click save. If I add any character it will save exactly as I typed into the database but if on of the columns contains a double inverted comma it shows everything before the inverted comma, example: 40" Samsung will show the 40 but everything after the zero won't show.

Please help

Comment: you need to show your code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" is called quotation mark and is special character in HTML, PHP and SQL. What probably happens is that somewhere appearance of " changes the meaning of code. How to avoid that? Escape data. To escape html use PHP function htmlspecialchars. For escaping SQL you need to use database extension specific function or parameterized statements. For example for Mysqli you can use real_escape_string.